# Wordpress Side Menu Admin Panel Default Order numbers List?

Tags: wp-admin, admin-menu

Is there a page on the WP documentation someplace that lists the order numbers for the default menu items in the Admin panel on Wordpress? Cannot find anything on line that just gives a clear numbering system such as "Posts = 1" "Media = 5" etc etc.

I'm using a plugin that allows to add an order number for placing a custom post on the menu area but it would be handy to know the breakdown of the numbering between the default menu options instead of guessing 1, 5, 10 and 20.

I remember seeing something like this before that broke it down but cannot find it at all on Google. Only ways to rewrite the order using functions.php file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default order:

```
2 – Dashboard
4 – Separator
5 – Posts
10 – Media
15 – Links
20 – Pages
25 – Comments
59 – Separator
60 – Appearance
65 – Plugins
70 – Users
75 – Tools
80 – Settings
99 – Separator
```

[add_menu_page() code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page)

Comment: Hey @anton, Thanks a million for this. I honestly found it quite hard to come across it. This is perfect. Thanks again.